# Azure Analysis services connection to storage account not working

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services, azure-storage-account

We have azure analysis services setup that pulls data from ADLS Gen2 (JSON files). When we try to process or model the tables from within SSMS it throws the following error - –

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The
> credentials provided for the AzureBlobs source are invalid.

When I open up the storage to all networks then no issues. However I am worried about the security aspect opening up storage account like that.

**My Quesiton is :** Any pointers to why SSMS would throw such an error?
Tried to create SP as admin on AAS server and added the same SP to storage blob as contributor but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add contributor will never help for solve this problem.

As you can see in practice, this has nothing to do with RBAC roles.

The key to the problem lies in the network, you need to set the storage firewall.

You have two ways:

1, Add the outbound ip of the service you are using to the allowed list of storage .

2, Or integrate your service with Azure VNET, and then add this virtual network to the allow list of the storage firewall.

This is all of the ip address of azure service we can get:(You need to add the ip address of the corresponding service to the allowed list about firewall in storage.)

https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20200824.json

Comment: Thanks! But i don't think Azure Analysis service has a public IP or a range. From what I have read I might have to use the IP range for the entire region..